# What should an XML post request look like for WCF RESTful service with a single parameter?

Tags: xml, wcf, post, rest

I am having trouble working out what my XML should look like when performing a post request through WCF REST services.
When using a datacontract i have no problem at all but when i just want to send across one parameter for example an int, i get the following error - "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed. "

```
[OperationContract]  
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/DeleteUser", Method= "Post")]  
bool DeleteUser(int userId);
```

What should my XML look like?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Found out where i was going wrong.
'Post' needs to be 'POST'. Case matters
And the xml is   -int- value -/int-

Answer (score 1):

DJ -- The only way I've found to do what you were originally asking is to swipe the example from this link.  It uses a Stream class to bring in the post parameters in the body of the HTTP request. Then you have to slog through it manually...

Hope [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1588431.aspx/1?How%20to%20post%20data%20to%20WCF%20REST%20without%20entity%20) helps.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/DeleteUser/{userId}", Method= "Post")]
bool DeleteUser(string userId)
{
   int actualUserId = Int32.Parse(userId);
   ...
}
```

ps: Why are you using POST with a single parameter?

---

I can see *not* using GET if you want to Delete, but then why not use HTTP DELETE ?
In this case the URI Template would be /user/{userId} and the Method = "Delete".

There's no payload, no XML to pass.

[Rob Bagby explains](http://www.robbagby.com/rest/rest-in-wcf-part-viii-hi-rest-implementing-delete/)

the code would look like

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/User/{userId}", Method= "Delete")]
bool DeleteUser(string userId)
{
   int actualUserId = Int32.Parse(userId);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cheeso ill use the DELETE for this. But for curiosity sake, if i was to create a user or something similar with just the 1 parameter, what would the xml look like?

Comment: To create a user, you'd have to define the schema for user (what are the datafields? firstname, lastname, etc).  Then the XML would likely be <user><firstname>DJ</firstname><lastname>Dozier</lastname></user> . And you'd use POST, with a RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml .

Comment: I understand that if i use a datacontract thats what the xml would look like. But is it possible to post data without using a data contract.
For example if this was the operationcontract  - 
bool Addnumber(int number)
what would the xml look like?

Comment: I think you need to ask a new question

Comment: that is what my original question was.

Comment: IF there's just a single param, it can be in the URL path, there's no XML. 
just like the first answer I have, above.

Answer (score 0):

Im using a post as its a delete function so i dont want to use a parameter in the uri. Get calls should be for getting data.

Thats not the problem. The userId is an int and is expecting and int. My question is if doing a post using one parameter what should the xml look like?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are performing a POST operation to the resource. The URL might be as follows:

```
http://localhost/SampleApplication/DeleteUser
```

Below is the request format that you need to have

```
<int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">55</int>
```

The above xml needs to be part of the message body.